# Why is Git reporting autocrlf as true?

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

I'm on Windows and autocrlf has never been an issue. I have always had it set to `false` in a system-wide config and never changed it to true. However, in one of my repos, the `git config core.autocrlf` started reporting "true".

This is my system-wide config (C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\config):

```
[core]
    ...
    autocrlf = false
```

There is then **no mention** of autocrlf in both my global config (C:\Users\Borek\.gitconfig) and myproject\.git\config. Still, when I run

```
git config core.autocrlf
```

it prints out true. What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Git probably isn't using the file in Program Files.** There should be a .gitconfig file wherever git considers its home directory to be. You can find out where that is in Git Bash with

```
echo ~
```

In my case, although I have git installed to the same place as you, running the above prints `/z`, which is a network drive. My global .gitconfig is at `/z/.gitconfig` - you should have an equivalent file. Have a look in there, and see what core.autocrlf is set to.

Comment: You're right, my system-wide config was "overwritten" by [cmder](http://bliker.github.io/cmder/) which I use as a console on Windows. It comes with its own embedded msysgit and their default ("system"-wide) config file sets autocrlf to true.

Comment: @Borek Stunning. Please report that bug to cmder.

Comment: Did that already. Turns out there is a Git-less cmder distribution that just uses the system msysgit installation. That basically fixed my issue.